# Undefined symbol: __libc_single_threaded on Jetson nano using tensorflow lite

Tags: tensorflow, raspberry-pi, tensorflow-lite, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano

I'm trying to run the [raspberrypi tflite object detection model](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/raspberry_pi) on my jetson nano. I installed all the required libraries and followed the setup on their github page, but I keep getting the error:

```
Undefined symbol: __libc_single_threaded on Jetson nano using tensorflow lite
```

When trying to run my code. Does anyone know what the problem could be? I'm using a python environment on Ubuntu 18.04 (the one flashed on the SD Card) with python3.8 on the default nvidia image for the jetson nano installed from their website.

And yes, I ran:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

Thinking it may be a problem from there, but nothing

I also updated pip within my local environment and installed :
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6.

Plus I installed the GLIBCXX_3.4.29 with:
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt install -y g++-11

With the info [from this source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1393285/how-to-install-glibcxx-3-4-29-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I got exhausted by the gyrations. I just install tensorflow-support 0.4.3 and the problem went away.

```
(.venv) er@er:~$ pip install tflite-support==0.4.3
...
(.venv) er@er:~$ python
Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 22 2023, 10:22:35) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tflite_support
>>>
```